# Creating buttons using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, ready

I am trying to display a button "Add Something" when the button "Add" is clicked. Everything is working fine except for the button "Add Something", I can't seem to append a new button. The problem seems to be revolve around Javascript. My jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o4tbf6y2/6/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
      var i=1;
     $("#add_row").click(function(){
      $('#a'+i).html("<td>"+ (i+1) +"</td><td><input name='code"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Code' class='form-control input-md'  /> </td><td><input  name='name"+i+"' type='text' placeholder='Name'  class='form-control input-md'></td><td><p data-placement="'top'" data-toggle="'tooltip'" name='add"+i+"'><button class="'btn btn-primary btn-xs'" data-title="'Add'" data-toggle="'modal'" data-target="'#myModal'" >Add Something<span class="'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'"></span></button></p></td> ");

      $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="a'+(i+1)+'" class="text-center"></tr>');
      i++; 
  }); });
  </script>
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Are you sure the code is exactly the same  you copied here? Because there is a < missing at least. Also, have you checked the log for errors?

Comment: Everything is working fine except for the "Add Something" button, if i remove it, it is able to display

Comment: create a js fiddle for it, you will find solution in minutes :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o4tbf6y2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o4tbf6y2/6/

Comment: i have edited the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

you miss a "});" and have you ever import the jquery and you should use tbody to append

```html
<tr id="a'+(i+1)+'" class="text-center"></tr>
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you haven't added the "add_row" id to the button, so that the click can be hook in to it.

Comment: Looks like you haven't see `add_row` id right after table and div closing tag.

Comment: Oh, okay. Fair enough.

In my defence, it's all pretty darn confusing, with buttons and links and "Add" and "Add Something". I'm not 100% sure what the desired effect is, to be honest. Looks like you get it though. ;P